# How to format Date & Time in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, format

I have a userform to display excel worksheet named "results" using OWC Spreadsheet 11.0. The steps could be found from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406319/display-a-part-of-an-excel-sheet-on-a-userform-using-vba/17407415#17407415

Now i encountered a problem that the date, time (start,end) all are converted into numeric. Therefore, is there a way to lock the format from the worksheet itself or a VBA code that could work the same way.

This is how the image looks

[image]

Comment: where is the date and time values been pulled from? Can you post the vba code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the relevant columns with the relevant format. For example

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Spreadsheet1.Cells.Range("A1:B3").Value = _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B3").Value

    Spreadsheet1.Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Siddharth Rout
I have tried out your method but met with a Run-Time Error '9' : Subscript out of range. My Column B entries could be as many as 30 rows. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many rows has data in there. The above code is for the entire column. What is your spreadsheet's control's name?

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:

```
Range("").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

or "dd/mm/yyyy" or whatever else combination.

Example 2:

```
Range("").Value = Format(Range("").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

or "dd/mm/yyyy" or whatever else combination.